# Поиск похожих изображений в Интернете?

Tags: delphi, изображения

Как осуществить поиск похожих изображений в сети интернет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Или вы проиндексировали/проиндексируете изображения в интернете. Или пользуйтесь готовыми сервисами.

Те, которые я встречал:

- [Google Images](http://images.google.com)
- [Yandex Images](http://images.yandex.ua/)
- [TinEye](http://www.tineye.com/)

Как связать с Delphi, можно начать смотреть отсюда - [Google Image Search API](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide). Продолжить тут [TinEye Commercial API](http://www.tineye.com/commercial_api)

Comment: TinEye как раз ищет похожие изображения и умеет это делать!

Comment: @eprivalov1, спасибо, исправлю. Сам я им не пользовался :)

Comment: я как-то баловался с яндексом (после статьи на хабре) тоже вроде похожие выдает)

Comment: :) удаляю, к чёрту, свои догадки о том, какие похожие, как нет.

Comment: Что-то вообще не вижу теперь в яндексе как искать по загруженной картинке)

Answer (score 1):

Существуют online-сервисы, так как [TinEye.com](http://www.tineye.com/), приведенный [xEdelweiss](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7017/xedelweiss), - он как раз и позволяет искать похожие изображения.

Что касается программной реализации, то это конечно возможно - алгоритмы существуют, но вы представляете сколько сайтов вашей программе придется облазить пока она будет формировать БД ? А потом её нужно будет обновлять и расширять...
Другой способ - посылать запросы online-сервису (тому же [TinEye.com](http://www.tineye.com/), например) и парсить ответы.
Хотя, возможно есть сервисы предоставляющие API (скорее всего они платные) - если интересует, поисковики вам в помощь.